# Executable jar doesn't show up the icons/images used in the application

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, executable-jar

While writing my application (used Eclipse as my IDE), I didn't realize the problem that my images would not be eventually bundled in the jar. Now after completing the project and creating the executable jar, I bumped into this problem. I have around 50 java classes, and I have used images/icons extensively in most of these classes (e.g. in menus, as `JLabel` icon, in buttons, as tab icons, etc). I have used the `ImageIcon` API in most of the cases. 
One example:

```
JLabel myHeaderImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/myHeader.jpg"));
```

What's the best way to pull in the images in the jar. Do I need to change the way I have used the images in my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getResource()`:

```
JLabel myHeaderImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/myHeader.jpg")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put a **full path** to ur images, such as in my case:

ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("X:/ProjektyNetBeans/GUITest/src/data/world.png");

Then Clean and Build. File .jar will work fine. Good luck.